# Android programming setContentView does not show xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, oncreate

In onCreate method I have this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_sin_login);
    .....
```

Here is my activity_main_sin_login

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:background="@drawable/estilofondobarraprincipal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/carga_inicial" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why my app does not show this layout when the activity starts? I have used clean eclipse option but it does not work. My application only shows a blank page

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: What are you doing in `onCreate()` later - are you blocking the UI thread?

Comment: Hi laalto, I need to perform one task in AsynTask and get data from user preferences saved in mobile

Comment: How are you running the asynctask? Make sure there's no `.get()`

Comment: What do you mean exactly with. Get?

Comment: What I really mean that you should post more of your `onCreate()`. And the thing to avoid is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()

Answer (score 0):

use **android:src** inplace of **android:background**

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/carga_inicial"/>
```

Comment: removing your relative layout background should work

Comment: i have checked it it and it's working for me,if you are facing any specific problem post that or else post your scenario better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
 >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/carga_inicial" />

</RelativeLayout>
```